Withdrawal ETHwallet to kraken account
I am new in the field. Could someone help me in checking thetype of ETH account of the wallet: 0x750CD8AB19f5A97b2371BE646D26C24029275aaB and let me know if there is a way to recover my investment into my kraken exchange account?
The wallet was created by a trading company. I have log-in access but not the second secret key. I have transfered ETH into it several times from my KRAKEN exchange account directly into the wallet. Now, I need to take ETH out on the same kraken exchange account but my request is blocked for validation and I am told that the transaction is not possible due to the risk of fiscal control. They say that only a transfer to an ETH wallet of my bank of origin would be possible but we already know that the bank does not offer this account type. I am afraid that I am a victim of scam. Please help me understand! Thank you in advance!

If you don't have the private key corresponding to the wallet 0x750CD8AB19f5A97b2371BE646D26C24029275aaB then there is nothing you can do. Usually the keywords "trading", "validation" are a red flag. Unfortunately it is very likely the company is a scam and you won't be able to recover your funds. Centralized exchanges do KYC, AML before you deposit anything. You should try to contact local authorities in your country to investigate a possible fraud.
